# PHP returns NULL running Python Script with Tensorflow

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, macos, tensorflow

First of all, sorry if this seems like a duplicate question. But honestly, nothing has worked for me. Searched for hours here.

Okay, so I have a python file called `label_image.py`, the code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
print("TEST")
```

When I tried to call the script via a PHP file:

```
$outpt = shell_exec('python label_image.py');

var_dump($outpt);
```

this returns NULL.

But if I remove the import of tensorflow in the python file, so it's the following:

```
import numpy as np
print("TEST")
```

and runs the PHP file, it outputs the following:

```
string(5) "TEST "
```

With this test, it can be deduced that the line of importing Tensorflow causes the return of NULL.

I tried putting this on top of my PHP file, as I've read on another stackoverflow thread:

```
PUTENV("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/");
```

but it doesn't work, still. I am using Mac OS by the way.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you run `python label_image.py` from your shell?

Comment: Check the program exit code using `exec()`. It is highly possible that the python script can not find `tensorflow` and throwing some exception/error.

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is a faulty installation of tensorflow. Try running the script from a shell and see if it throws an error or something. I'm pretty sure `shell_exec` will return `null` if the exit code is anything other than 0.

Comment: @TomKarzes , if running from shell means running it from the Terminal, it produces the expected output (not null, but printing TEST)

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I have not ran `exec()` yet, but the python script itself works perfectly with tensorflow, even when it's executed from the terminal. Only calling it from PHP causes this error (NULL). Sorry if I understand you wrongly.

Comment: @AlexanderEjbekov I ran the py script from the terminal and it works. Only by calling it from PHP that it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a problem locating the tensor flow library, I think you may try setting `PYTHONPATH` like this:

```php
<?php

// PYTHONPATH setup
$pythonpath = getenv('PYTHONPATH'); // see if there is current setting
$additional = '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/'; // the location where the Tensorflow library is installed.
putenv(($pythonpath === false) ? "PYTHONPATH=$additional" : "PYTHONPATH=$pythonpath:$additional");
```

Comment: This sadly does not work. My Pythonpath was false, I tried to set it to my actual python path (the path I wrote in this post was wrong), but still does not work.

Comment: @SeanSaoirse: What does `php -r 'var_dump(shell_exec(\'python -c "import sys; print(\\\'\n\\\'.join(sys.path))"\'));'` show? Does it contain the path to your TensorFlow installation?

Comment: @SeanSaoirse: Also, what does `php -r 'var_dump(shell_exec(\'python -c "import tensorflow"\'));'` return?